# Acrobat creating acrolock#######.tmp files?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I had a user the other day who was having issues saving PDF files using Acrobat. What they were trying to do was simply open the PDF file in question, make a simple change, and save the file back as the original file name. The result of this was a error message from Adobe saying it couldn't save the file (don't remember the exact error message). It also DELETED the original file! So if you don't save it to a different location or a different name you could actually LOSE the file!!!

The files in question are located on a server shared via Samba. The shares are setup using Windows ACLs. I initially thought something might be wrong with the permissions, but now I'm leaning away from that since no other user has brought this issue to my attention. And they open, edit, save these files all day long. Also I believe the user said they didn't have an issue if they used a different computer. Now I'm thinking it is more likely that something is wrong with Adobe on that computer.

I was looking in the folder where she was having issues and I see a bunch of files that look like;

> acrolock####.tmp

See image here (since I don't have enough rep) http://s17.postimg.org/m8zfkm7vz/Capture.png

I searched around online and couldn't find any info on files with this naming. Very surprised. My guess is that for whatever reason her computer/adobe installation is causing the Adobe files she opens to remain in a open/lock state and therefore not allowing it to be overwritten.

Does anyone have any insight to this? Anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like I am able to reproduce the issue on my end as well after downloading the latest adobe acrobat. So it isn't "just" the user. Now that I have the error message I was able to find information to the issue. It appears to be an issue with new Adobe release 11.0.10 and protected mode.

Info [HERE](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7091592)

> My users started to experience this issue for files on network shares as well once Adobe Reader was updated to 11.0.10.
>
> It has to do with Protected Mode being turned on.  I don't know if it was off by default & now it is on with the update but turning it off changes Adobe Reader's behavior back to what the users expect - a prompt warning you if you want to overwrite the existing file & then selecting Yes to overwrite.
>
> To disable Protected Mode:
>
> Start Adobe Reader
>
> Edit - Preferences - Security (Enhanced)
>
> Uncheck Enable Protected Mode at Startup
>
> Close Preferences & Close Reader
>
> Now open a file from a network share & you Adobe saves as it used to.